# How to do right alignment with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want something like

```
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
    4 + 3 + 2 + 1
                …
                1
```

How to do it with MathJax?

Answer (score 8):

A method using AMS math environments:

```
\begin{align}
5+4+3+2+1&\\
4+3+2+1&\\
\vdots&\\
1&
\end{align}
```

\begin{align}
5+4+3+2+1&\\
4+3+2+1&\\
\vdots&\\
1&
\end{align}

Multicolumn:

```
\begin{align}
5+4+3+2+1&&5+4+3+2+1\\
4+3+2+1&&4+3+2+1\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
1&&1
\end{align}
```

\begin{align}
5+4+3+2+1&&5+4+3+2+1\\
4+3+2+1&&4+3+2+1\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
1&&1
\end{align}

**Remark:**

1. MathJax does not differentiate `align` and `align*`.
2. MathJax automatically identifies `\begin{...}...\end{...}` as math environments, so there is no need to enclose them with `$$...$$`.
3. Details of math environments are in [AMS doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Comment: +1 especially for the remarks.

Answer (score 3):

I just found that `aligned` is right-aligned by default. So it could simply be done like this:

```
$$\begin{aligned}
5+4+3+2+1\\
4+3+2+1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{aligned}$$
```

Result:
$$\begin{aligned}
5+4+3+2+1\\
4+3+2+1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

`$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}5&+&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\ &&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\ &&&&&&&&\vdots\\ &&&&&&&&1\end{array}$$`

You will get:$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}5&+&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\
&&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\
&&&&&&&&\vdots\\
&&&&&&&&1\end{array}$$

Comment: +1 easy to follow and looks elegant.

Comment: That seems overly complicated.  If the goal is to right-align, why not just use a single right-aligned column?  e.g. `$$\begin{array}{r}5+4+3+2+1\\4+3+2+1\\\end{array}$$` $$\begin{array}{r}5+4+3+2+1\\4+3+2+1\\\end{array}$$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, that's simpler.

Comment: @XanderHenderson but it's not as spaced as it is in José's answer :p

Comment: After reading all in this post:  I concluded.. $\phantom{\begin{array}{}5&+&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\&&4&+&3&+&2&+&1\\&&&&&&&& \vdots\\&&&&&&&&1 \end{array}}$

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. I consider the tighter spacing to be a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @XanderHenderson of course it's not a bug, I'm just saying that I  prefer the visualization of the spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation is by semi-manually adding the correct space with `\phantom`, which could be useful if it appears inside more complicated objects:
\begin{align}
15
&=5+4+3+2+1\\
-5+15
&=\phantom{5+{}}4+3+2+1\\
-4-5+15
&=\phantom{5+4+{}}3+2+1\\
-3-4-5+15
&=\phantom{5+4+3+{}}2+1\\
-2-3-4-5+15
&=\phantom{5+4+3+2+{}}1\\
\end{align}

code (without things on the left of the $=$ sign)

```
\begin{align}
&=5+4+3+2+1\\
&=\phantom{5+{}}4+3+2+1\\
&=\phantom{5+4+{}}3+2+1\\
&=\phantom{5+4+3+{}}2+1\\
&=\phantom{5+4+3+2+{}}1\\
\end{align}
```

NB the `{}`s are needed so that `+` gives the spacing of a binary operator.